# Best way to add a new column to a large table? (MySQL - MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, myisam, alter-table

Here's more info on the table that needs to be altered:

- 15GB size MyISAM table with **Index** around 5GB
- Over 100 million rows
- MySQL 5.1 on RHEL 5 with 4GB RAM
- Currently live online

What's the best way to add **a couple** of new column (minimum 2 columns) to a large table like this? With minimum downtime. Just using direct ALTER table commands would take hours if not a day or two to finish.

***Additional question***: Will it affect the length of time needed to add new columns if the new column default value are set to NULL instead of having a 'pre-defined' value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make online changes to a table you can use [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html)

```
    pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=sakila,t=actor
```

The table will be blocked for a few seconds when it switches new and old tables. The table though must have a primary keys and not have triggers.